# Growing sequence of $a_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> **Question**: Find all strictly increasing sequences $a_n$ , such that $a_2 = 2$, and $a_{mn} = a_m\cdot a_n$ for all integers $m, n$

How can I solve it? In particular, I'd like to show that $a_n = n$ is the only such sequence.

**My work**

I have something like this:

$a_{1}$ = 1

$a_{2}$ = 2

$a_{4}$ = 4

Let m = 3 and n = 2

I designate $a_{3}$

So:

$$a_{1} < a_{2} < a_{3} < a_{4} < \dots < a_{n}$$

So:

$$1 < 2 < a_{3} < 4  \implies   a_{3} = 3$$

But how to continue?

Comment: what does "of the total words" mean? Also, what have you tried?

Comment: $$a_4=a_{(2)(2)}=(a_2)(a_2)=(2)(2)=4$$

Comment: @Jon.Don No problem. Now can you find, for all positive integers $n$, a general form for $a_{2^n}$?

Comment: Nathan, not yet :( how I can to this?

Comment: How I can formalize the solution?

Comment: @Jon.Don I took the liberty of editing (heavily) your post to make it more clear. Please try to be as clear as possible when writing your question and in your successive edits. Since the question is now well-posed, I voted to reopen the question.

Comment: By the way, I have a solution which I'll post as soon the post is reopened.

Comment: Oh, Thanks :) I wait for reopened

Comment: You should not cancel the content of your question, it can be helpful for others in the future. I revert back your edit to bring the question in the last (acceptable) form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sequence is strictly increasing, it turns out that it's pretty easy. I believe it is also true if we allow non-strict inequalities, but I haven't been able to prove it.

First, it is easy to see that this sequence is determined by the values we assign to prime numbers. So if $n = p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ then $$a_n = a_{p_1}^{\alpha_1} \cdots a_{p_k}^{\alpha_k}$$

From this it's clear that $a_{2^n} = 2^n$. It is also clear that $a_n = n$ is a sequence which works.

We want to show that is the only sequence.

The op already found that $a_1 = 1$ and $a_3 = 3$. Now suppose there exists (some) primes $p$ such that $a_p \neq p$. Let $q$ be the minimum of such numbers (ie, $a_n = n$ for all $n < p$).

Now since $a_{q-1} = q-1$, we have $a_q \ge q$. We want to show that $a_q > q$ is impossible.

And indeed, $a_{q+1}$ is not a prime and all of his prime factors are less than $q$. Since the prime-indexed numbers less than $q$ are just the primes themselves, it follows that $a_{q+1} = q+1$. But then $$q-1 < a_q < q+1$$

So the only possibility is that $a_q = q$ for all primes and this implies $a_n = n$ for all $n$

Comment: Wow, greats prove my friend :)

Comment: hm what if a number of complex x < q such that ax different x?

Comment: @Jon.Don by definition of $q$, for every $x < q$ we have $a_x = x$

Comment: How do you know q + 1 is complex?

Comment: @Jon.Don You should say composite, complex refers to imaginary numbers and stuff. However, since $q$ is prime (hence odd), $q+1$ is even, hence divisible by $2$, hence composite

Comment: do you think that the proof is 100 % correct?

Comment: @Jon.Don I don't understand the meaning of that sentence, sorry.. Can you reformulate?

Comment: and if we have q =2?

Comment: @Jon.Don we already know $a_2 = 2$ and $a_3 = 3$. The smallest $q$ could be is $5$

Comment: Maybe we go in chatroom?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29088/discussion-between-jon-don-and-ant).